# How can I determine the probability of chained events in Combinations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I want to create an app that would be used as a helping tool in an indie card game called [the resistance](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41114/resistance). For this I need to make sure my math is good in order for me to start my project. A use case example would be as follows:

Out of a group of 10 people there are 6 good guys and 4 bad guys. As per the rules I want to have 3 people out of that entire group of 10 to go on a in-game mission, I want to know my probability of any randomly selected 3 people that they contain a bad guy.

So based on my understanding, I calculate that in that group of 3 (out of a total of 10) I have a 40% chance of choosing just one bad guy, 16% of choosing exactly 2 bad guys and 0,64% of all three of them being a bad guy. In other words there is a total of 62,4% chance of having at least 1 or more bad guys in that team.

So as per the rules of the game, the team of 3 goes on a in-game mission and the results (secretly) come in that there has been 1 out of 3 possible sabotages with 100% certainty that it was caused by a bad guy and I don't know who it was. So now I have a 33% certainty that one of those 3 is surely a bad guy.

Now, by the rules of the game I have to send 4 people on the next mission. Since I do not wish the next mission to fail, I know that I cannot take all 3 people from the first mission and include a fourth player because it will surely fail again.

I want to take into consideration the following continued scenario: Let's assume with absolute certainty that the first mission that failed actually had only 1 bad guy. That would mean that in first sub group of 3 people there is 1 bad guy and in the other subgroup (that haven't went on the mission) there are 3 out of 7 bad guys, because it totals out to 10 people.

I want to consider taking just 1 guy from the first mission and then 3 guys from the group of 7 that haven't went but I know that the group of 7 now contain 3 bad guys. This is where I get lost in calculating.

I don't know if it is better to actually take 2 guys from the first subgroup of 3 where I know there is only 1 bad guy and then 2 guys from the group of 7 where I know it has 3 bad guys.

Can I get some input on this please? I hope I have made this question clear.

Some formulas and thoughts would come in much appreciated on the exact scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The probability of having at least one bad guy. Let $B$ be the event at least one bad guy is chosen

$$P(B) = 1- P(\text{not }B) = 1- \frac{6\times 5\times 4}{10 \times 9 \times 8} = 1- \frac{120}{720} = 1-0.167=0.833$$

So you have an 83.3% chance of choosing at least one bad guy. As the first guy chosen has a 6/10 chance of being good, the second 5/9, and the last 4/8.

$$P(B) = 1 - P(\text{not }B) = 1 - P(1\text{ is good}, 2\text{ is good},3 \text{ is good})$$

2. If I understand your second question correctly, you want to know what the optimal number from each group to take on the second mission (assuming the first mission indeed had only one bad guy) in order to maximise the success of the second mission. Since this is a simple case we can actually calculate these probabilities fairly easily:

Scenario 1: None from first group, all from second group

$$P(B) = 1- P(\text{not }B) = 1-\frac{5 \times 4 \times 3}{7 \times 6 \times 5} = 1-\frac{60}{210}=0.714$$

Scenario 2: 1 from first group, 2 from second group

$$P(B) = 1- P(\text{not }B) = 1-\frac{2 \times 5 \times 4}{3 \times 7 \times 6} = 1-\frac{40}{126} = 0.682$$

Scenario 3: 2 from first group, 1 from second group

$$P(B) = 1- P(\text{not }B) = 1-\frac{2 \times 1 \times 5}{3 \times 2 \times 7} = 1-\frac{10}{42} =0.761$$

Scenario 4: 3 from first group, 0 from second group

$$P(B) = 1$$

Since there's at least 1 bad guy in the first group.

So the optimal choice is to take 1 from the first group, 2 from the second, as it provides the lowest probability of getting a bad guy.

I hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: The second part was to actually get 4 people on the second mission, not three. But Im trying to figure that math based on your example. Also does the 33 percent chance of the guy being a bad guy from the first group affect the outcome of the second mission?

Comment: Ok I get the math now, thanks a lot for taking the time to explain. If I need 4 good guys it ends up being the worst if I grab all four from the group of 7, whereas it's about 90% chance that I will get a bad guy if I choose either one or two people from the group of 3. But I still don't understand if the 33% chance of choosing the bad guy from the first group plays any role in the outcome of my result?

Comment: It should play a role if theres 1 or 2 bad people in the firist group

Comment: So I then multiply 0,33 for 1 and 0,66 for 2 guys in my second group probability?